# Android: какой самый правильный способ прочитать файл из интернета?

Tags: android, многопоточность, kotlin, android-sdk, coroutine

Мне нужно прочитать файл из интернета при инициализации своего приложения.
Я написал такую функцию:

```
private fun urlRead() {
    val url = URL(MY_URL)
    val stream = url.openStream()
    val v = stream.read()
}
```

И вызываю эту функцию из onCreate. При вызове функции openStream приложение выбрасывает исключение NetworkOnMainThreadException. Я так понял, что чтение файлов из интернета нужно делать в отдельном потоке. Поиск по форумам и статьям привёл к тому, что один из самых просты способов - это использовать [AsyncTask](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask). Но в документации на него указано, что он deprecated и лучше использовать coroutines. Однако документация на корутины написана очень невнятно, есть подозрение, что перед тем как её читать, нужно знать что-то ещё, но что именно и где про это можно прочитать в документации не указано.

В общем, не могли бы вы привести простой пример кода, как с помощью корутины в Kotlin в Android прочитать содержимое файла из интернета?

Comment: https://github.com/Kotlin/kotlinx.coroutines

Comment: Я делал с помощью AsyncTask и все работает

Comment: Style-7 - понятное дело, что AsyncTask работает. Просто создатели Android SDK считают что есть способ лучше, причём настолько лучше, что они объявили AsyncTask устаревшим. Вот и хотелось бы понять, что это за способ.

Comment: And - статей про корутины в Kotlin в интернете полно. Только они как-то так хитро написаны, что совершенно непонятно как скрестить их код с моим кодом.

Answer (score 2):

Для сетевых операций отлично подходит библиотека [Retrofit](https://square.github.io/retrofit/)